# Cannot read property 'target'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, typescript, loops

I'm trying to increase a value by targeting a specific item in a loop.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    <ion-button (click)="increment(i)">
      <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
    </ion-button>
    <ion-input type="number" value="{{quantity}}"></ion-input>
</div>
    
    
    public items:Array<string> = []; //i
    public quantity:number = 0; //quantity

    increment(index:number){
     (this.quantity[index].target as HTMLInputElement).value[index] = this.quantity[index] + 1;
     console.log(this.quantity[index])
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't complete, but as i can see you are trying to access an element from your variable that is a type of `number` `this.quantity`.

You should access variable `items[index]`

And also i guess you `this.quantity` variable should be array also if you want to store quantity for every item individually:

```js
public items:Array<string> = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4']; //i
public quantity:number[] = [0, 0, 0, 0]; //quantity

increment(index:number){
 this.quantity[index] = this.quantity[index] + 1;
 console.log(this.quantity[index])
}
```

Comment: Increase the value of an input type number when clicking a button inside an item ngFor loop (only a specific item) anyway says NaN after click on increment(i) event

Comment: So, where you get items to print with ngFor, just loop trough all items and make array with same length as number of `items` and set them to 0 or what ever you need. I will modify my example

Comment: I updated my answer. Does this satisfy your example? If not, can you add more code for clarification